# Раздельная конфигурация babel для web-приложения (браузерный JavaScript) и node.js в одном проекте

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babel

Как известно, NodeJS используется не только как серверный язык, но и как средство для автоматизации Frontend-разработки (примерами таких NodeJS-инструментов являются Gulp и Webpack). Если gulp-конфигурация или webpack-конфигурация довольно объёмная, одним `gulpfile.js` и `webpack.config.js` тут не обойтись - может получиться целая библиотека для автоматизации работы с проектом.

Для удобства, хотелось бы использовать `babel` не только для кода веб-приложения (обычно собранного Webpack-ом), но и для кода для автоматизации сборки проекта средствами NodeJS. (В первую очередь это нужно для того, чтобы пользоваться тем же синтаксисом импортов-экспортов, что и в Webpack-приложении). В общем случае конфигурация babel для webpack-приложения и библиотеки автоматизации на node.js не обязана быть одинаковой, а потому появляется закономерный вопрос: как можно разделить конфигурацию babel для webpack-приложения (то есть речь идёт о браузерном JavaScript) и библиотеки автоматизации (созданной на NodeJS)?

Правильно или нет, можно говорить долго, но я прописываю конфигурацию babel для webpack-приложения непосредственно в webpack-конфигурации (примерно так):

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader?blacklist[]=regenerator',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['env', {'modules': false}]
              ],
              plugins: [
                'syntax-dynamic-import',
                'transform-runtime'
              ]
            }
          },
          'eslint-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Поэтому файл `.babelrc` можно отвести под nodejs. Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: еще раз: вы хотите одним конфигом вебпака собирать `node.js` и фронтенд, но что бы `babel` конфиг был разный?

Comment: @ThisMan, прошу прощения за то, что недостаточно чётко поставил задачу. Webpack планируется использовать только для фронтенда, а для node.js - только babel.

Comment: а сама конфигурация для бабеля одинаковая для обеих сборок? Или разная? Вообще можно просто указывать кастомный файл для бабеля ( `.babelrc` это название по умолчанию )

Comment: @ThisMan, предполагается, что конфигурация babel разная для двух сборок (иначе этот вопрос о "раздельной конфигурации" не имел бы смысла).